# How to Generate a Set of Textboxes from a Dropdown Menu Autofilled with Random Numbers?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I would like to use a dropdown menu to allow the selection of a set number of three textboxes where each number set of textboxes should contain a unique set of numbers. Currently, the dropdown menu does create the desired number of sets of textboxes, for example, selecting 5 generated a set of 5 textboxes filled with random numbers. The problem is that they are all the same sets of random numbers.

I would like something where a selected number in the dropdown menu would generate the desired sets of textboxes, then clicking on a Generate Numbers button would fill the sets of textboxes with random numbers where each set is unique. Can this be done with Javascript, JQuery or do I need to use something else?

Here's my code so far. Thank you very much for your help.

```
<?php
//generate set of random numbers from 1 to 10000
function RandomNumbers($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
}
$num = (RandomNumbers(1,10000,10000));
$random1 = $num[0];
$random2 = $num[1];
$random3 = $num[2];
?>

<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
//this is the code which I am not sure how to develop >>>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $counter = 0; // initialize 0 for limiting textboxes
        $('#dropdownadd').change(function(){
            $('#dropdowndiv').html(""); // when the dropdown change set the div to empty
            $loopcount = $(this).val(); // get the selected value
            for (var i = 1; i <= $loopcount; i++)
            {
                //this adds textboxes using dropdown menu but inserts the same number set into each set of textboxes
                $('#dropdowndiv').append('<div><form>Number Set #'+i+'<input type="text" name="num1" class="textbox1" value="<?php echo $random1; ?>" /><input type="text" name="2" class="textbox2" value="<?php echo $random2; ?>" /><input type="text" name="3" class="textbox3" value="<?php echo $random3; ?>" /></div>'); 
            }
        });
    });
</script>


<div id="dropdowndiv">
<!-- this is where textboxes will appear -->
</div>
<div class="choices">
    <span>Adding Textboxes using Dropdown Menu</span>
    <select id="dropdownadd">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
    </select>
</div>
</html>

<HTML>
<form name="form" method="post">
<input type="text" name="num1" id="var1" value="<?php echo $random1; ?>" >
<input type="text" name="num2" id="var1" value="<?php echo $random2; ?>" >
<input type="text" name="num3" id="var1" value="<?php echo $random3; ?>" >
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Generate Numbers">
</form>
</HTML>
```

Comment: The JS [`Math.random()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) is what you need if you want to generate random numbers client-side.

Comment: @nnnnnn is completely right. All you have to do to ensure they're unique is to check if the value of any inputs is the same as the number generated...I'll fiddle it..inc

Answer (score 1):

Try this up
http://jsfiddle.net/fedmich/F79nf/

Math.random
Math.round()
for loop
and jquery appends

Answer (score 1):

[This is the solution I came up with](http://jsfiddle.net/w7gCX/)

Fedmich's got the same approach, I just used the code you provided and modified what needed to be modified, and left alone that which did not need to be modified (what did I even just say).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is you complete solution which shows no of form sets with three text boxes according to selection of drop down option value and when we click on button called "Generate Button" attached with each form which generate unique value for every input sets.

TRY this Solution on Codebins : http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpb7